# Project Euler Problem 5: Smallest Multiple of 1 through 20

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge

In continuing to learn C# I solved [Problem #5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) with my code below. I tried to follow the suggestion to [write [my] program so that it looks like the specification](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161213/131748). Where can I improve my code?

The problem is as follows:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetSmallestEvenlyDivisibleNumber());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static bool isEvenlyDivisible(int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
        {
            bool returnValue = true;
            for (int i = lowerBound; i<= upperBound; ++i)
            {
                if (value % i != 0)
                {
                    returnValue = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }

        static int GetSmallestEvenlyDivisibleNumber(int lowerBound = 1, int upperBound = 20)
        {
            int testNumber = 2521;

            while (!isEvenlyDivisible(testNumber, lowerBound, upperBound))
            {
                testNumber += 1;
            }

            return testNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start at upperBound because it is more likely to fail

Comment: Not only start at `upperBound`, but increment the target by `upperBound` once you find one that does work for it. You'll then *only* check numbers divisible by `20`, which means you check 1/20 of the numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two focus areas for this review, first some style and code comments, and then a little discussion on a more optimal solution.

### Code and Style Comments

- *Mostly good and clean code* – I like to see clean, properly spaced, well named code, as it makes it a whole lot easier to understand (and easier for you to maintain in the long run).
- *Stick to `PascalCase`* – This is already commented upon in another answer, but having equal naming and standards throughout your code really helps readability and eases the understanding of code. Which in turns, makes your code maintable.
- *Avoid magic numbers* – Within `GetSmallestEvenDivisibleNumber()` you use `2521`. This number pops out of nowhere in the context of the code. Not good. In addition, it introduces a bug if you try to find the solution for any range with `upperBound < 10`.
- *Comment your code* – It is not given what the `IsEvenlyDivisible` method actually does, and I would spend some time commenting upon what it does. Something along the lines of *Checks whether `value` is a proper factor of all the numbers in the range `lowerBound` to `upperBound`*.

### Alternate Solution

Most Euler problems have at least two major solution: The brute force solution, and an optimal solution. You've implemented the brute force of testing each and every number to see if it matches the criteria. In some cases the brute force can be improved somewhat, like skipping all the odd numbers, check for ending of 0 or 5, verify that the value is dividable by 3, and so on... This will usually lead to a somewhat faster solution, but when tackling the higher Euler Problems that'll not be enough.

Therefore it is a good idea to start looking for optimal solutions, and what is really asked for. In this case what is the number `2520`, and how have they derived at it? So what we now about that number:

- Is is dividable by the numbers in the range `1` through `10`
- By nature of previous statement, it also needs to be dividable by all of the factors of each of numbers in the range, so let us decompose the range:

\begin{align}
1 & \rightarrow 1 \\
2 & \rightarrow 2 \\
3 & \rightarrow 3 \\
4 & \rightarrow 2 * 2 \\
5 & \rightarrow 5 \\
6 & \rightarrow 2 *3 \\
7 & \rightarrow 7 \\
8 & \rightarrow 2*2*2 \\
9 & \rightarrow 3*3 \\
10 & \rightarrow 2 * 5
\end{align}

- Grouping these factors we find that we have 3 * `2`'s, 2 * `3`'s, 1 * `5`, and 1 * `7`. Based upon these factors, we can compose any of the range, and as it turns out: \$ 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 = 8 * 9 * 5 * 7 = 2520\$

In other words if you decompose each of the numbers of your range, and then count how many of each you need to create each of the numbers, this can be used to calculate the answer directly.

To help you get on the way for the range `1` through `20` let us decompose the final numbers as well:
\begin{align}
11 & \rightarrow \mathbf{11} \\
12 & \rightarrow 2 * 2 * 3 \\
13 & \rightarrow \mathbf{13} \\
14 & \rightarrow 2 * 7 \\
15 & \rightarrow 3 * 5 \\
16 & \rightarrow 2 * 2 * 2 * \mathbf{2} \\
17 & \rightarrow \mathbf{17} \\
18 & \rightarrow 2 * 3 * 3 \\
19 & \rightarrow \mathbf{19} \\
20 & \rightarrow 2 * 2 * 5  \\
\end{align}

I've **bolded** the numbers not already present in our set, and those are \$11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 2 = 92738\$. So the end result will be: \$92738 * 2520 = 232792560\$.

So there you have yourself a new challenge: *Implement this alternate, but more efficient algorithm*.

Comment: The numer `2521` is not a magic number, it's named and it's called `testNumber`. Improving brute-force by skipping numbers by ceretain criteria is no longer brute-force but math and no brute-force has any chances against math. It's cheating when you still call it brute-force.

Comment: It is a magic number in the sense that it appears out of nowhere without explanation. There is no reasoning in the code as to why it is there.  If used, it should've been a constant with some explanation, unless you like magic numbers sprinkled out in your code.

Comment: @t3chb0t, And you are still brute forcing the solution even when you are skipping a few of the candidates.

Comment: Regarding `Comment your code`. I've read that code should not state *what* is being done, that should be self-evident. Rather comments should explain *why* it's being done that way. Do you mean adding a description for the method [as shown here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary).

Comment: @IvenBach A comment stating "For loop from 1 to 20" is superfluous, a comment like "Loop through all candidates", or as given in my answer "checks whether value a proper factor of all the numbers in the range lowerBound to upperBound" are something else. They _can_ describe the _what_ or the _why_, or simply help those reading the code understand what is happening in the next code segment (or method).

Answer (score 4):

In terms of simply making your code better (keeping with the brute force approach) there are a couple things you could note.

1. You only need to check the even numbers because the answer is divisible by 2
2. Only numbers ending in 5 or 0 are divisible by 5

Putting those together we can see that the solution must be divisible by 10. That means we can start our search at 2520 and add 10 each time:

```
static int GetSmallestEvenlyDivisibleNumber(int lowerBound = 1, int upperBound = 20)
{
    int testNumber = 2520;

    while (!isEvenlyDivisible(testNumber, lowerBound, upperBound))
    {
        testNumber += 10;
    }

    return testNumber;
 }
```

**Edit:**

As Peter Taylor pointed out in the comments, you can take the logic further to incrementing by 2520 each time because the final solution needs to be divisible by all the numbers 1-10. However, the main thrust of my answer was supposed to be that you don't need to brute force and you can compute the solution directly.

---

Your code looks good: you have consistent spacing and good, descriptive names. `isEvenlyDivisible` should be `IsEvenlyDivisible` as all methods are `PascalCase` in C#.

I would remove the optional parameters from `GetSmallestEvenlyDivisibleNumber` as we've now made it much more specific to the case of 1-20.

You can calculate this directly without needing to brute force see [this blog](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-5/) for a good explanation of that approach.

Comment: If you're going to change the increment, you could at least apply the logic fully and set the increment to 2520.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think I was so preoccupied with getting to the suggestion about throwing away the brute force that I've ended up being a bit dim. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

## helper variable not necessary

> ```
> static bool isEvenlyDivisible(int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
> {
>     bool returnValue = true;
>     for (int i = lowerBound; i<= upperBound; ++i)
>     {
>         if (value % i != 0)
>         {
>             returnValue = false;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return returnValue;
> }
> ```

You don't need the `returnValue` here because you can `return` as soon as the condition is `true` like that:

```
static bool IsEvenlyDivisible(int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; ++i)
    {
        if (value % i != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

## preincrement

> ```
> while (!isEvenlyDivisible(testNumber, lowerBound, upperBound))
> {
>     testNumber += 1;
> }
> ```

This loop does not necessarily need to have a body. You can do the same with the `++` pre-increment operator inline:

```
while (!IsEvenlyDivisible(++testNumber, lowerBound, upperBound)) ;
```

Comment: I would strongly emphasize that you _can_ do the pre-increment, but I wouldn't suggest doing so, as having that empty `while` body really cripples the reading and understanding of the code.

Comment: @holroy I'm of a different opinion ;-)

Comment: Knowing that something can be done is very beneficial. For my sake, I'll err on the side of caution and wrap it `{ ... }` to explicitly show what's going on.